# WPF dynamic creating objects based on user's choice

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am new to WPF and trying to make simple tetris, so I will have "define shapes" window where I allow user to define shapes and colors of blocks in this window there are 4 grids filled with buttons that allow user to define shape, by clicking on it, now my question is: How can I create shapes based on user's choice? I am fairly new to WPF so I would really appreciate if you could be very detailed.

Here is screenshot so you can visualize:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfZez.jpg)

Comment: You can fill each grid member as per the shape created by user.

Comment: Please be more specific on what you already done and where are you stuck at?